# meaning of shell script `export CONFIG=${X_CONFIG:-${Y_CONFIG}}`

Tags: shell

I have seen the following usage of script.

```
export CONFIG=${X_CONFIG:-${Y_CONFIG}}
```

Question> what is the real meaning of this script?

Thank you

Comment: Is it really reasonable to have a question asking what syntax X means for every possible syntactical construct in a language? That's the direction this goes down.

Comment: ...for relevant references, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073, http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html#lbBB, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Parameter_Operations, etc.

Comment: As an aside -- all-caps variable names are reserved by convention for variables with meaning to the shell or system; see fourth paragraph of the relevant spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, reserving the namespace of variables with at least one lower-case character for application-defined use. (While only environment variables are explicitly in-scope for that portion of the POSIX spec, shell variables share that namespace, so the convention applies to them as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${X_CONFIG:-${Y_CONFIG}}}` is a [parameter expansion for a default value](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value).

That is to say: It expands to the value of `X_CONFIG` if set to a non-null value, or `Y_CONFIG` if `X_CONFIG` was either unset or null.

Thus, the effect of the statement as a whole is to assign a variable `CONFIG` to have an identical value to either `$X_CONFIG` or `$Y_CONFIG`, and export that variable to the environment.